# Не растягивается div. Не могу установить нужную высоту

Tags: html, css

по умолчание мой div должен иметь высоту 450px. Но у меня есть сообщения о ошибке валидации. Когда они появляются то див не растягивается и выводит кнопки за пределы дива вниз как на скрине ниже

http://prntscr.com/o2hywg

Я игрался тем что устанавливал height: auto но он тогда изначально растягивает длину буд-то уже видны строки валидации как на скрине ниже.

http://prntscr.com/o2hze8

игрался тем что устанавливал разные значения min-height max-height Но результат по факту тот же.

вот css блока

```
.div-profile {
 height: 450px;
 width: 420px;
 background-color: white;
 margin-left: 10%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px -2px #434343;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px -2px #434343;
 }
```

вот сам div

```
 <div class="div-profile rounded border">
  <form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitProfile()">
    <div style="margin-top: 30px; height: 50px;" class="center-full- 
 content">
      <input placeholder="Name" type="text" style="margin-right: 10px; 
 margin-left: 20px;" formControlName="name"
        class="register-input-first left rounded border" />
      <input placeholder="Surname" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; 
 margin-right: 20px;"
        formControlName="surname" class="register-input-first right rounded 
 border" />
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="formErrors.name" class="alert alert-danger error-div">
      {{ formErrors.name }}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="formErrors.surname" class="alert alert-danger error-div">
      {{ formErrors.surname}}
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 10px; height: 50px;" class="center-full- 
  content">
      <input placeholder="Email" type="text" formControlName="email" 
 class="register-input rounded border" />
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="formErrors.email" class="alert alert-danger error-div">
      {{ formErrors.email}}
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 10px; height: 50px;" class="center-full- 
   content">
      <input placeholder="Nick name" type="text" formControlName="nickname" 
 class="register-input rounded border" />
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="formErrors.nickname" class="alert alert-danger error-div">
      {{ formErrors.nickname }}
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 10px; height: 50px;" class="center-full- 
 content">
      <input placeholder="Password" type="password" 
 formControlName="password"
        class="register-input rounded border" />
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="formErrors.password" class="alert alert-danger error-div">
      {{ formErrors.password }}
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 10px; height: 50px;" class="center-full- 
  content">
      <input placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" 
  formControlName="confirmPas"
        class="register-input rounded border" />
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="formErrors.confirmPas" class="alert alert-danger error-div">
      {{ formErrors.confirmPas }}
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 10px; height: 50px;" class="center-full- 
content">
      <input value="Create User Account" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid" 
type="submit"
        class="create-user rounded" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Как сделать так что по умолчание было 450пк а при выводе ошибок валидации он нормально растягивался.

Comment: укажите для блока:
min-height: 450px;
height: 100%;

Comment: Спасибо, сработало...дайте ответ и я отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

укажите для блока: `min-height: 450px; height: 100%;`